# Is the error rate of IBMQ devices full-scale (% FS) or on percentage of reading (% RD)?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

The error rates that I found on the calibration files are given in percentage, but I couldn't find whether it is calculated on full-scale (% FS) or on percentage of reading (% RD). If I do $20000$ shots and found $|00\rangle$  at $5000$ with an error rate of $1\%$, should it be $5000 \pm 200$ or $5000 \pm 50$? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentage error rates in the calibration files give the average readout error across all qubits. So, in your example, $20000$ shots of which $5000$ measured $|00\rangle$ on a backend with an average qubit error rate of $1\%$ would correspond to an *estimated* uncertainty of $5000 \pm 50$. To more accurately quantify measurement uncertainty you'll want to look at the single-qubit error rate for each qubit and the CNOT error rate for each connection, see [How to get the CNOT error rate between 2 qubits on a given IBMQ Backend?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13864/how-to-get-the-cnot-error-rate-between-2-qubits-on-a-given-ibmq-backend) and [Is current information about readout-errors of qubits on IBM quantum devices available on some internet page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472783/is-current-information-about-readout-errors-of-qubits-on-ibm-quantum-devices-ava)